# How can join two django querysets in one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I need order a Queryset by date in desc order, but i need put in the end the objects at the end, I do this:

```
qs1 = Model.objects.exclude(date=None).order_by('-date')
qs2 = Model.objects.filter(date=None).order_by('-date')
```

and my list is:

```
l = list(qs1)+list(qs2)
```

There is a more efficiently way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Model.objects.extra(select={'nodate':'ISNULL(date)'}, order_by=['nodate', '-date'])
```

Comment: So then use `'date IS NULL'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're looking for all the objects that have a date ... and all the objects that don't have a date?

Wouldn't this work better:

```
Model.objects.order_by('-date)
```

Anyway, here's a good place to start ... read about Django filter chaining: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#id1.

As a side note, isn't your query canceling itself out?

```
>>> d = MyModel.objects.filter(date=None).exclude(date=None).order_by('-date')
>>> d
[]
>>> d.query.get_compiler('default').as_sql()
('SELECT "date" FROM "table" WHERE ("table"."date" IS NULL AND NOT ("table"."date" IS NULL)) ORDER BY "table"."date" DESC', ())
```

I'm probably not understanding what you're asking...

Comment: The queries do seem to cancel each other out... unless it has something to do with grouping that I'm just not seeing. Looks like @diegueus might want the objects with no date at the end of the list, and maybe .order_by('-date') puts them at the beginning?